# JavaScript работает и одновременное не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня следующая задача, мне нужно сделать таблицу 2х2, и у каждой плитки этой таблицы есть кнопка, которая должна открыть скрытый div, в котором iframe. Если открывается iframe, то меняется grid-template-columns и grid-template-rows. С 30vw 30vw для столбцов, и 20vh 20vh для строк, на 95vw для столбцов, и вариативно для строк. Вариативно - это если к примеру я открыл первый фрейм, но при этом у меня уже был открыт третий, то мой grid-template-rows будет равен 110vh 20vh 110vh 20vh, а если я открываю только первый, то соответственно 110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh.  До того как попытался сделать вариативную высоту строк, у меня все работало, ширина и высота первого контейнера уменьшалась и увеличивалась, iframe появлялся, но как только написал код на вариативность, сразу все поломалось: iframe не появляется, ширина увеличивается, но не уменьшается, высота увеличивается только у 1 элемента...

Логика моего js следующая: Проверяем, скрыт ли тот элемент, за который отвечает кнопка вызвавшая метод, если да, то смотрим, какие ifram'ы уже были показаны, и в зависимости от этого выставляем высоту строки, и ставим `display: block;`. Если же этот элемент показан, то делаем все тоже самое, но выставляем display: none;

Вот кусок html кода:

```
<div id="projects-grid">
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="">
                    <button class="a-btn">
                        <h2>Go to Tribute page</h2>
                    </button>
                </a>
                <button class="show-btn" onclick="firstBtnClick()">
                    <p id="first-show-p">Click to open site</p>
                </button>
                <div id="first-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/V6Dh8R60/Tribute-Page-Preview.png" alt="">
                    <!-- <iframe src="https://codepen.io/YouAreMe12/full/bGRdxZg" frameborder="0"></iframe> -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="">
                    <button class="a-btn">
                        <h2>Survey form</h2>
                    </button>
                </a>
                <button class="show-btn" onclick="secondBtnClick()">
                    <p class="show-para">Click to open site</p>
                </button>
                <div id="second-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/V6Dh8R60/Tribute-Page-Preview.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="">
                    <button class="a-btn">
                        <h2>Product landing page</h2>
                    </button>
                </a>
                <button class="show-btn" onclick="thirdBtnClick()">
                    <p class="show-para">Click to open site</p>
                </button>
                <div id="third-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/V6Dh8R60/Tribute-Page-Preview.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-tile">
                <a href="">
                    <button class="a-btn">
                        <h2>Technical documentation page</h2>
                    </button>
                </a>
                <button class="show-btn" onclick="forthBtnClick()">
                    <p class="show-para">Click to open site</p>
                </button>
                <div id="forth-hidden">
                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/V6Dh8R60/Tribute-Page-Preview.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css:

```
#projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30vw 30vw;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 20vh;
  grid-gap: 9rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}
.project-tile {
  background: var(--main-gray);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
}
#first-hidden {
  pad: var(--main-cyan);
  display: none;
}
#second-hidden {
  display: none;
}
#third-hidden {
  display: none;
}
#forth-hidden {
  display: none;
}
iframe {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 87vw;
  height: 89vh;
  border-bottom: 7px solid var(--main-white);
}
```

и JS с адаптивной высотой:

```
function firstBtnClick() {
    //start
    if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display == "none") {
        //second is shown
        if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and third
            if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //and also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
                //second and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
            //second is hidden third is shown
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //third and forth
            if (!document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
            //only forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("first-show-p").textContent = "Click to hide site";
        document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //column check
        if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "95vw";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "30vw 30vw";
        }
        //second
        if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and third
            if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
                //second and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            //only second
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
            //third
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //third and forth
            if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            //only third
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
            //forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("first-show-p").textContent = "Click to open site";
        document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
function secondBtnClick() {
    //start
    if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display == "none") {
        //first is shown
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and third
            if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //and also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
                //first and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
            //first is hidden third is shown
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //third and forth
            if (!document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
            //only forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("second-show-p").textContent = "Click to hide site";
        document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //column check
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "95vw";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "30vw 30vw";
        }
        //first
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and third
            if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
                //first and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            //only first
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh";
            //third
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //third and forth
            if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            //only third
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
            //forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("second-show-p").textContent = "Click to open site";
        document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
function thirdBtnClick() {
    //start
    if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display == "none") {
        //first is shown
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and second
            if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //and also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
                //first and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
            //first is hidden second is shown
        } else if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and forth
            if (!document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
            //only forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("third-show-p").textContent = "Click to hide site";
        document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //column check
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "95vw";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "30vw 30vw";
        }
        //first
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and second
            if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //also forth
                if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
                //first and forth
            } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            //only first
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh";
            //second
        } else if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and forth
            if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
            }
            //only second
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
            //forth
        } else if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("third-show-p").textContent = "Click to open site";
        document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
function forthBtnClick() {
    //start
    if (document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display == "none") {
        //first is shown
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and second
            if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //and also third
                if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
                //first and third
            } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
            //first is hidden second is shown
        } else if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and third
            if (!document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 110vh";
            }
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 110vh";
            //only third
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 110vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 20vh 110vh";
        document.getElementById("forth-show-p").textContent = "Click to hide site";
        document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        //column check
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none" ||
            document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "95vw";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "30vw 30vw";
        }
        //first
        if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //first and second
            if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                //also third
                if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
                }
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
                //first and third
            } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
            }
            //only first
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh";
            //second
        } else if (document.getElementById("second-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            //second and third
            if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
                document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 110vh 20vh";
            }
            //only second
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 110vh 20vh 20vh";
            //third
        } else if (document.getElementById("third-hidden").style.display != "none") {
            document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh 110vh 20vh";
        }
        document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh";
        document.getElementById("forth-show-p").textContent = "Click to open site";
        document.getElementById("forth-hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

И без:

```
function btnClick(){
if (document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "95vw";
    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "110vh 20vh 20vh 20vh";
    document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display = "block";
}else {
    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "30vw 30vw";
    document.getElementById("projects-grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "20vh 20vh";
    document.getElementById("first-hidden").style.display = "none";
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Оформите в сниппет, не удобно копировать код чтоб понять что вы получаете.

Comment: @Greg-- в таком коде никакой сниппет не поможет))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я хочу понять какой результат Богдан хочет получить

Comment: Я хочу сделать таблицу, которая по умолчанию имеет размер 2х2, в каждой ячейке таблицы имеется кнопка, и скрытый div, в котором сидит iframe. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку:
1) появлялся iframe
2) менялся размер текущей ячейки
3) оставался размер других ячеек которые уже были "вскрыты".
Именно это я пытался сделать в js, идет проверка на "вскрытые" ячейки таблицы, и исходя из этого меняется размер ячеек, через grid-template-rows.

Comment: Что такое сниппет, и как его добавить?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы было приблизительно как в этом gif: https://postimg.cc/t7jQvWz0

Answer (score 0):

Осилить текст вопроса и его код лично я не смог)) **НО**

> Я хочу чтобы было приблизительно как в этом gif: postimg.cc/t7jQvWz0 –
> Богдан Иманкулов 21 час

Если смотреть на эту гифку, то вы не представляете на сколько просто решается эта задача и на сколько вы себе её усложнили.

**Сразу подсказка**: помимо id в мире css есть ещё классы. Они помогают работать с сущностями, которые имеют общий тип, в целом что-то общее.

Итак, всё, к чему сводится ваша задача это: если хотя бы один блок открыт - то все блоки расположить вертикально на всю ширину страницу. **ВСЁ**.

---

- При клике на кнопку ставите нужному div класс "opened" или убираете его, если он уже есть на этом самом конкретном div (а не у всех).
- При клике на любую из кнопок должна срабатывать одна единственная функция, которая проверяет, если есть хотя бы один блок с классом "opened" - тогда **всем** присваивать соответствующие стили. **Подсказка:** стили можно задать в *CSS*, а блокам задать именно эти заранее прописанные классы. Если элементов с данным классом 0 - то убрать стили или убрать заранее определённые классы в *CSS*. Тогда они станут опять 2x2
- Всё

Comment: Я понимаю, что есть еще и классы, я могу разобраться с шириной, но проблема в том, что я не могу увеличивать высоту. Как было показано в html & css у меня родительский контейнер - грид. И мне нужно что при открытии первого контейнера(плитки, фрема, или как еще его обозвать), у меня увеличивалась высота этого самого контейнера(в grid-template-rows у меня за 1 контейнер отвечает 1 строка, и чтобы когда  я нажал увеличить, то у меня высота становилась не 20vh, a 110vh). А когда я с УЖЕ открытым контейнером(уже 1 или более контейнеров имеют высоту 110vh), и открываю еще один

Comment: То у уже открытых высота остается такой же(110vh), и увеличивается у нажатого. Я на свежую голову переписал код, на другой логике, он стал более читаемым, и опять ошибка, но уже другая.

Comment: Ссылка на новый вопрос (и также js): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336578/Почему-style-gridtemplaterows-возвращает-пустую-строку

Comment: @БогданИманкулов Я расписал вам логику. Она ровно та, что вам нужна и ровно то, что вы мне сейчас повторили в комментарии) Перечитайте. Попробуйте понять

Comment: @БогданИманкулов по сути, этот код будет занимать десяток строчек (и то лишь из-за объёмного кода навешивания слушателей). А сама логика умещается в две